# Custom Number of Items in Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

All- I have an app in which the user enters the names of players in a game. He/she can enter 2-4 players. The app takes the names and puts them into a spinner. When the user enters 4 players it works great but when they enter only 2 or 3 players, the spinner has 2 or 1 (respectively) empty spaces. How can I make it so when the user enters a number of players less than 4, only that number of names appears in the spinner (no empty spaces). Here is the code I am using:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"No Owner", message, message2, message3, message4};
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.owner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

message= Player 1,
message2= Player2, 
etc.

Sample code welcome, and thanks for your time.
EDIT:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.ANOTHER_MESSAGE);
    String message3 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.YET_ANOTHER);
    String message4 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.AND_ANOTHER);




setContentView(R.layout.next_main);
```

Comment: Where does the user enter the number of players and how does it interact with the Spinner? Please post more of your code.

Comment: The user enters the players in an earlier activity. See edit for receive intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check which messages are empty and then modify your items array based on that information.  The goal being to pass an array to your ArrayAdapter with no extra spaces in it

Edit:

```
List<String> playersList = new ArrayList() ;
        if(!message.equals("")){
            playersList.add(message);
        }
        etc..  

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, playersList);
```

Comment: You could use a List rather than an array for your players names and build it dynamically.  See edit.

Comment: Sweet that was it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're importing your player names into a string, I would run string compare to see if each string matches the default value, if there is no player filling that slot. In other words, if
    `message.compareTo("")`
returns 0, don't include that in `items`, which would be best used as an ArrayAdapter. You can do this through a simple if block.

Example code:

```
ArrayAdapter items = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, int textViewResourceId);    

if (message.compareTo("") != 0) {
    items.add(message);
}
if (message2.compareTo("") != 0) {
    items.add(message2);
}
....
```

And you would keep going with the rest of your items, using the resulting array (which you can pull out using `toString()`) to generate the Spinner.

EDIT: Fixed constructor code.

EDIT 2: Fixed textViewResourceId in the constructor.

Comment: How would I do this as my players are in a 'String[] items = new String[] {"No Owner", message, message2, message3, message4};' not a R.id.contentlist?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the R.id.contentlist references a TextView, which is in your larger layout. The TextView is how you get the resulting String array. I'll edit it above.